# Create Custom Ruby Docker Images using RHEL7 Universal Base Image

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, rvm, rbenv

I'm trying to create individual docker images for multiple ruby versions using RHEL7 ubi as my base image.
From my exhaustive research **rbenv** seems like the preferred method to go.
I've been successful at installing the ruby version of my choice but executing rake tasks within the container returns **sh: rake: command not found** error.
I know it has something to do with setting the correct PATH but I'm not sure about how to do so.

PS: using the official ruby image is not a feasible option for my usecase.

Comment: You don't generally use version managers like `rvm` or `rbenv` in Docker: since an image contains only one thing, just install the relevant Ruby version as the "system" Ruby.  Can you edit the question to include the Dockerfile you have so far, and how you're launching the resulting container?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Installing Ruby as system i.e. `yum install -y ruby` installs `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]`. My goal is to have docker images with a specific ruby versions say 2.5.1, 2.6.0, etc